# How to make link should be clickable inside <p> tag?

Tags: html, paragraph

I have a paragraph and inbetween there is a link. It will look like for example:

Lorem Ipsum https ://www.lipsum.com/ is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. https ://www.lipsum.com/ It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

This should look like:

Lorem Ipsum https://www.lipsum.com/ is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. https://www.lipsum.com/ It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Links inside paragraphs are clickable by default. We can’t tell why yours are not without a [mcve].

Comment: Unless you are asking how to turn a URL in plain text into a link, in which case you would need to use a programming language to do that.

Comment: … in which case (the second one, just mentioned by Quentin) you should also do some proper research, because that would be anything but a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check you code if everything is alright. Your code should be like this:

```
<p> Lorem Ipsum <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/">https://www.lipsum.com/</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="https ://www.lipsum.com/">https://www.lipsum.com/</a> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
```

Also, always try to post your code, because when we can't see it, then it's hard to help you. Talking from my own experience.

Comment: Actually this paragraph is not static, there can be any link uer can type in a paragraph but after submission, that paragraph should identify links in that and provide them to click